# How do I modify an existing class with a class containing 2 methods?

Tags: scala

How do I create an Inventory class that has 2 methods (add and subtract) which adds or subtracts an amount to an Item class, and return a new Item with its count adjusted correctly?

Language: Scala

What the code should do:

```
val Shirts = Item("Hanes", 12)

val Inv = new Inventory

scala> Inv.subtract(5, Shirts)

output: Item(Hanes,7) 

scala> Inv.add(5, Shirts)

output: Item(Hanes,17)
```

The code I have:

```
case class Item(val brand: String, val count: Int)

class Inventory  {
  def add(amount:Int):Int={
    count+=amount   
  }

  def subtract(amount:Int):Int={
    count-= amount  
  }
}
```

Note: I can't figure out how to modify the Item class with the Inventory class containing 2 methods. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Scott, you have to put all code in the code syntax highlighting. Fix that please.

Comment: Ashwin, Forgive me, I'm still learning. It looks like someone fixed it, and I will do that for next time.

Comment: No it's all good man! Just letting you know, so it's easier to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
class Inventory {
  def add(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    item.copy(count = item.count+amount)     
  }

  def subtract(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    item.copy(count = item.count-amount)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: per your comment, to add a check that the amount > 0 (if the amount is <= 0, I simply leave the item unchanged):

```
class Inventory {
  def add(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    if (amount > 0) item.copy(count = item.count+amount) else item
  }

  def subtract(amount:Int, item: Item): Item = {
    if (amount > 0) item.copy(count = item.count-amount) else item
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you add if else statements in that code? For instance when the amount must be greater than 0. When I add in if else statements I get a type mismatch error.

Comment: @ScottWright I edited my answer to show a straight-forward way an if-else can be incorporated.